# MQTT shared subscriptions to solve the duplicated issue in the distributed system

Tags: javascript, mqtt, subscription, shared

We build the server to subscribe the topics from another MQTT server. It works perfectly when we have only one server. However, when we scale it to multiple servers it went wrong. Because each of servers receive the same message from the subscription, everything performs multiple times.

[MQTT v5](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt5-essentials-part7-shared-subscriptions/) solves this problem, but I have the 2 questions:

1. Is the [MQTT.js](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) supports this feature? I cannot find it in the documentation.
2. If we are still using MQTT v3.1.1, any alternative solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. The client side doesn't need to do anything to support Shared Subscriptions as it's all done with a topic prefix. This means MQTT.js will work just fine.
2. There are some MQTT brokers that have support for Shared Subscriptions while working at MQTT v3.1.1 level. The different broker implementation were done before the v5.0 spec was written but the spec was very much based on these implementations so they work in a very similar fashion.

There is also nothing MQTT v5.0 specific about how Shared Subscriptions work, (nothing in the new header space) so there is no reason why it shouldn't work for a v3.1.1 client connecting to a v3.1.1/v5.0 compatible broker that offers the Shared Subscription feature.

I can't remember which brokers supported it at v3.1.1 so you will have to check which broker you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Because the implementation for the broker (MQTT server) is not under our control (provided by another service), is there other solution if they do not provide the shared subscription?

Comment: No, it's important to remember that MQTT is a pub/sub protocol, not a message queue

Comment: Do you mean shared subscriptions in the MQTT v5.0 specific not stable? We are worry about using v5.0 not suitable due to specific changed (not stable) in the future. Do you have any reference to implement shared subscription under v.3.1.1?

Comment: I'm saying before the v5 spec was released (or even considered), some brokers had support for shared subscriptions, but because there was no spec, their implementations had subtle differences. With the v5 spec, there is now a single definition that all brokers should conform to (if they have implemented v5). Apart from IBM Message Sight I can't remember the names of any of the brokers that had v3.1 Shared Subscriptions, you will have to check for yourself whatever broker the service you are using.

Comment: For spec of the shared subscriptions in v5, will it be changed in the future? Or we could implement it now due to it is stable.

Comment: That's how specification versions work, if things in the future change then it would be ratified in the next version (e.g. v7) but anything that complies with v5 will always behave the same way.